# How to wait for an event to finish - without using Wait() method?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am developing an application in which I need to wait for a event to complete before a new request is raised. For example:- If some one clicks on an abort button in a record processing application I need to make sure that the application exists only when the processing of the current record has been completed. I am not using threads in my application.

My question is what are the efficient ways by which we can achieve it ? A sample code would be of great help.

Comment: This magic doesn't exist.  The BackgroundWorker and Task classes were designed to help you implement this.

Comment: @Bose_geek I assume you mean "exits" instead of "exists"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you are not using any kind of asynchronous processing in the background (by any means, not just plain threads), then your application closing will be postponed till current processing is finished.

So this kind of behaviour you get out of the box.

Comment: So what I can understand is that even if I write Application.close() in the Abort button event it will wait for the background processing to get over ? So, if 1000 record needs to processed and I click abort at the 998th record it will finish up processing 998th record and then exit. Is this what u meant?